# How php sorts the files

Tags: php, zip

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($uploadDir.$_FILES['zip']['name']);
$zip->extractTo($uploadDir);
$zip->close();
unlink($uploadDir.$_FILES['zip']['name']);
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($uploadDir);
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO files(file) VALUES('{$fileinfo->getFilename()}, {$id})");
    }
}
```

I've uploaded a zip file, I'am wondering how php sorts the files? if the files are sorted by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, will php sort them in this order?

Comment: Have you tried testing it to see for yourself?

Comment: @GordonM no I'am too lazy to do that dude